# Confluent Kafka Python Client and modifying replication factor and partitions for a topic that already exists?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

There is [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/admin/__init__.py#L674) method in the confluent kafka api. I am curious if I can use this or another part of this api to modify/alter the replication factor and/or partition size?

It is possible to use this method to adjust a a topic with an active listener such as segment/retention times. I am starting to think replication factor and partitioning might be more complicated. [Here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html) is the documentation I've been combing through, but not seeing anything definitive as of yet.

I understand for partitions, we can modify by increasing the number (not decreasing).